# Why make '--dry-run' with $(MAKE) in a recipe result in an error?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

When I run `make --dry-run` on

```
all:
    false  # $(MAKE)
```

using GNU Make 4.2.1, I get back the following error. Why?

```
false  # make all
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Instead-of-Execution:

> The `-n`, `-t`, and `-q` options do not affect recipe lines that begin with `+` characters or contain the strings `$(MAKE)` or `${MAKE}`.

(`--dry-run` is an alias for `-n`.)

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable:

> ```
> subsystem:
>         cd subdir && $(MAKE)
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> As a special feature, using the variable `MAKE` in the recipe of a rule alters the effects of the `-t` (`--touch`), `-n` (`--just-print`), or `-q` (`--question`) option. Using the `MAKE` variable has the same effect as using a `+` character at the beginning of the recipe line.
>
> [...]
>
> Consider the command `make -t` in the above example. (The `-t` option marks targets as up to date without actually running any recipes; see [Instead of Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Instead-of-Execution).) Following the usual definition of `-t`, a `make -t` command in the example would create a file named subsystem and do nothing else. What you really want it to do is run `cd subdir && make -t`; but that would require executing the recipe, and `-t` says not to execute recipes.
>
> The special feature makes this do what you want: whenever a recipe line of a rule contains the variable `MAKE`, the flags `-t`, `-n` and `-q` do not apply to that line. Recipe lines containing `MAKE` are executed normally despite the presence of a flag that causes most recipes not to be run.

Your recipe contains `$(MAKE)`, so it gets executed despite `--dry-run`. `false` returns an exit status of 1, which is considered an error by `make`.

Comment: Wow. +1 Why is this a feature instead of a bug? (What's the use case?)

Comment: This is a critically important feature.  If you have a recursive makefile structure then running `make -n` at the top level is virtually useless unless it recursively invokes the sub-makes as well.